# why this javascript RegExp syntax will be infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, regex

-------------test.hta file code ------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>dead</title>
</head>
<body>
txt<textarea id="content" >
            <input name="" type="text" class="qu_te1n05ew" value="请输入您的E-mail地址" />
           <input name="" type="submit" class="qu_sbt02" value="提 交" />
           </textarea>
<button onclick="startCls();">start</button>

<script>
function getObj(id) {
    return 'string' == typeof id ? document.getElementById(id) : id;
}

function startCls() {
    var txt = getObj('content').value;
    var srcRe = /<\w+(?:\s[^<>]*(?:(?:'[^']*')|(?:"[^"]*"))?[^<>]*)*\s+src\s*\=\s*["']?(?:[^"' <>]*\/)?([^\/"'<>]+\.(?:gif|jpg|png))['" ](?:\s[^<>]*(?:(?:'[^']*')|(?:"[^"]*"))?[^<>]*)*\/?>/ig;
    alert(srcRe.exec(txt));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

------------code end-------

**why `srcRe.exec(txt)` loop and the hta is dead?but other test string it will work.**

the `srcRe` my mean is get a `img` tagname's src,and split it to get filename,but don't get no tagname's src,like `<b><img src="ss.gif"   </b>`,because it isn't a html tagname.have not end `>`;

this synax `(?:\s[^<>]*(?:(?:'[^']*')|(?:"[^"]*"))?[^<>]*)*`,the mean is if have a `<` or `>` ,it must be in the `''` or `""`,and other string must be not `<` or `>`;and is start by `<`,end by `>`;

Comment: Now thats a comment that needs a double vote!

Comment: [`TEXTAREA`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-TEXTAREA) does only allow parsed character data but not any other markup.

Comment: Sorry, but anyone who uses a regex like you've got deserves the consequences.  That is the least understandable line of code I've seen in weeks.  I'd strong suggest you do it another way (write actual JS to parse it) that's a lot more readable, maintainable and won't have the issue you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to debug this ghastly regex. But I can tell you why it fails. Breaking it down for "readability":

```
<
\w+
(?:\s[^<>]*(?:(?:'[^']*')|(?:"[^"]*"))?[^<>]*)*
\s+src\s*\=\s*["']?
(?:[^"' <>]*\/)?
([^\/"'<>]+\.(?:gif|jpg|png))
['" ]
(?:\s[^<>]*(?:(?:'[^']*')|(?:"[^"]*"))?[^<>]*)*
\/?
>
```

You can see that this can only match if there is a `.gif` or `.jpg` or `.png` in your string. Which it isn't, so the regex has to fail.

The problem now is that the regex engine takes a long time to figure this out because there are several instances of `[^<>]*` in your string, all of which can (and will try to) match the entire tag's contents, and (to add insult to injury) all of which are even enclosed in repeating groups. See line 3, broken down:

```
(?:
 \s
 [^<>]*       # optional!
 (?:
  (?:'[^']*')
  |
  (?:"[^"]*")
 )?           # optional!
 [^<>]*       # optional!
)*            # optional!
```

There are gazillions of permutations that the regex engine all has to check before being able to declare failure. In short, it's not an infinite loop, but a regex like this with input like that will like keep your computer busy until hell freezes over.

Hint 1: Read this tutorial on [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).
Hint 2: Don't use regexes to parse HTML. At least not if you don't [know exactly what you're doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491).

Comment: I mean write a regular expression to get `<tagname src="s.gif" >` tag's `s.gif`,some times maybe like `<tagname src="s.gif" title="<tip src='s.gif' >" >` too,but don't get `<tagname src="s.fig" none` or ` this is a text about "src = 's.fig'"`,so i keep try to  make sure the `<` or `>` can in the tag,but now i know it is difficult to do it by `regExp`,in my project, i can write a simple regexp to do what i want, and it  run better. my english is so bad,the web of  `catastrophic backtracking`,__see next comment

Comment: i only can  understand more then half;if you want to get string like `<tagname src="s.gif" title="<tip src='s.gif' >" />` from html string,except,use `for` and `if` to  find the `s`,then `r`,then `c`...and go back find `<`,and determine if the `<` in the `"" or ''`...,i would like to know, what do you do it, can anyone show me some example?because i can't easy to get substring like `<tagname src="s.gif" title="<tip src='s.gif' >" />` by regexp.thanks.

Comment: another way is `innnerHTML` then `getElementsByTagName('*')`,and use `for` to determine whice element is a img,then get it's src;